# clone uboot and embedded linux fw (openwrt) to a single binary image

Tags: linux, partition, embedded, u-boot

I have my embedded device with the following partition:

```
# cat /proc/mtd 
dev:    size   erasesize  name
mtd0: 00030000 00010000 "u-boot"
mtd1: 00010000 00010000 "u-boot-env"
mtd2: 00010000 00010000 "factory"
mtd3: 00f30000 00010000 "firmware"
mtd4: 00189fab 00010000 "kernel"
mtd5: 00da6055 00010000 "rootfs"
mtd6: 00600000 00010000 "rootfs_data"
mtd7: 00080000 00010000 "user"
```

I want to clone the u-boot + the openwrt image (linux) to a file that have this partition structure in order to clone this result image to all my devices

Comment: Why not copy the whole `/dev/mtd`? Those naked flash drives have no physical partitions, they don't even have a partition table, just some more or less hardcoded offsets, needed to be agreed upon between the U-Boot and linux. So don't try to `flashcp` single partitions unless you know they share the partition scheme.